# Need Help on writing a sql query for my database

Tags: sql

Trying to convert above table to below table format in SQL:

[image]

I am new to SQL

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please tag Oracle, SQL Server, mySQL, etc. so we know how to best help you =)

Comment: This operation is called `unpivoting` and the method is closely related with your DBMS as @JerryM. pointed out.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
select productnumber, 'price1' as prices, price1 as value
  from t where price1 <> 0 union
select productnumber, 'price2', price2 from t where price2 <> 0 union
select productnumber, 'price3', price3 from t where price3 <> 0 union
select productnumber, 'price4', price4 from t where price4 <> 0
```

Result:

```
productnumber  prices  value       
-------------  ------  -----
45678          price1     12           
45678          price2     43           
12345          price3     65           
45678          price1     32           
45678          price3      2            
12345          price2     43           
12345          price3    123          
45678          price3      5            
45678          price4      1            
45678          price2     12           
45678          price3      1
```

For the record, the data script I used to test in PostgreSQL is:

```
create table t (
  productnumber int,
  brand varchar(10),
  price1 int,
  price2 int,
  price3 int,
  price4 int,
  total int
);

insert into t (productnumber, brand, price1, price2, price3, price4, total) 
  values (12345, 'ami', 0, 0, 123, 0, 123),
         (12345, 'ami', 0, 43, 65, 0, 108),
         (45678, 'wax', 12, 43, 1, 0, 56),
         (45678, 'wax', 0, 0, 5, 0, 5),
         (45678, 'wax', 32, 12, 2, 1, 47);
```